# C++ time management and CPU

Tags: c++, windows, timer, cpu

Im trying to make a code work every 0.200 seconds, endup with this:

```
void Run()
{

    while( running ) 
    {

        QueryPerformanceCounter( &start );
        frame = (start.QuadPart - finish.QuadPart ) / (double)freq.QuadPart;
        while (frame > 1.00)
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter( &finish );
            std::cout << "Delta: " << frame << std::endl;
        }


    }   
}
```

The hardcoded "frame > 1" is just for an example. This code truely runs at one second, but i face two problems.
First - will i have any problems with accepting a network(tcp/udp ip) client?
Second - my cpu works at 25% of all its power because of this application - how do i avoid this unnecessary usage of CPU ?
Thank you in advice!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Also you don't update "frame" (you just update finish) in your loop.

Comment: Dummiest way to do. Im sorry but i DO NOT need to sleep a thread.

Comment: @Hakon89 Well, either you hog the CPU, or you do "nothing". Sleep does nothing. Or you do something else, e.g. wait for network I/O or wait for user input (which also does nothing) - also see http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html if you're creating a game.

Comment: If i wont update "frame" i wont get a delta of time. this temporary variable is used just for debug only

Comment: @nos you mean that when i add code it stop using cpu at  25% ?

Comment: @Hakon89 Um...you want to wait X ms then run without busy looping (aka using a full CPU core). You want to sleep your thread.

Comment: @Hakon89 Yes, Sleep does not use CPU. Waiting for I/O etc. does not use the CPU either.

Comment: @nos I need app to react on external events. So sleep wont help me.

Comment: Your thread isn't going to react to external events if you're stuck in a loop.

Comment: you can have two different threads.
1. One doing the event handling loop
2. Other doing the while(1) loop for performance query
I am assuming you have a multi core processor with os handling multi threading

Comment: @Hakon89 then that is a completely different question. you can either spawn an additional thread to deal with those events, or you can use Win32 events (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I suggest the other thread as if reacting to those outside events takes any amount of time you could get a delay in your counter. Either way you're looking at a muilthreaded application.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious that isn't nessisarily true, you end up doing that with embedded applications all the time (No os==no threads, only polling) something like `while (!kill_flag) { do_events(); iterate_loop();}`